# Is there a function to skip outfiltered rows when running a code in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, filtering

I have developed a template with which I can automate invoice reminders by outputting emails. Currently the code loops through the list outputting an email for each individual row (= each individual invoice). I would like to update the code so that it skips outfiltered rows in the excel doc to make it more efficient and easier in use.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub Send_email_fromtemplate()
Dim edress As String
Dim cc1, cc2, cc3 As String
Dim group As String
Dim number As String
Dim outlookapp As Object
Dim outlookmailitem As Object
Dim r As Long
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object

 r = 3

Do While Sheet1.Cells(r, 1) <> ""
    Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    'call your template
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.CreateItemFromTemplate([location])
    outlookmailitem.Display

    edress = Sheet1.Cells(r, 7)
    cc1 = Sheet1.Cells(r, 8)
    cc2 = Sheet1.Cells(r, 9)
    cc3 = Sheet1.Cells(r, 10)
    group = Sheet1.Cells(r, 4)
    number = Sheet1.Cells(r, 3).Value
    With outlookmailitem
       .To = edress
        .cc = cc1 & ";" & cc2 & ";" & cc3
        .bcc = ""
        .Subject = "First invoice reminder " & group
        
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:="{{Number}}")
                oRng.Text = number
                Exit Do
            Loop
        End With
        Set xInspect = outlookmailitem.GetInspector
  
       .Display
        '.send
    End With
    'clear your email address
    edress = ""
    
    r = r + 1
    
Loop
'clear your fields
Set outlookapp = Nothing
Set outlookmailitem = Nothing
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

I've tried to solve the problem using a Range function and ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible), but as the template will be filled with a variable number of rows (each time I send reminders) this is causing troubles, as the range differs each time.

Comment: `.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)` should work, but not iterating in the existing way. You should determine the last row, then iterate between each visible row, except the header. Is the header on the second row?

Comment: I have two header lines (on row 1 and 2). Would you suggest to change the code each time I remind depending on the number of rows?

Comment: No, I don't... The code itself should calculate the mentioned last row. I will post an updated code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next updated code. As I said in my above comment, it is able to calculate the last row on A:A, then create a range from visible rows of the filtered area and iterate between its rows:

```
Sub Send_email_fromtemplate()
 Dim edress As String, cc1 As String, cc2 As String, cc3 As String
 Dim group As String, number As String
 Dim outlookapp As Object, outlookmailitem As Object, olInsp As Object
 Dim wdDoc As Object, xInspect As Object
 Dim oRng As Object, lastR As Long, rngVis As Range, r As Range

lastR = Sheet1.Range("A" & Sheet1.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row on A:A
On Error Resume Next 'this is necessary in case of no any filtered visible cell
  Set rngVis = Sheet1.Range("A3:J" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
 If rngVis Is Nothing Then MsgBox "No visible filtered values in the necessary range...": Exit Sub

 Set outlookapp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application") 'you should set it only ones, outside of the iteration...
 For Each r In rngVis.rows 'iterate between the discontinuous (visible cells) rows
    'call your template
    Set outlookmailitem = outlookapp.CreateItemFromTemplate([Location])
    outlookmailitem.Display

    edress = r.cells(1, 7) 'extract the necessary values from the iterated row
    cc1 = r.cells(1, 8)
    cc2 = r.cells(1, 9)
    cc3 = r.cells(1, 10)
    group = r.cells(1, 4)
    number = r.cells(1, 3).Value
    With outlookmailitem
       .To = edress
        .cc = cc1 & ";" & cc2 & ";" & cc3
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "First invoice reminder " & group
        
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        With oRng.Find
            Do While .Execute(FindText:="{{Number}}")
                oRng.Text = number
                Exit Do
            Loop
        End With
        Set xInspect = outlookmailitem.GetInspector
  
       .Display
        '.send
    End With
    'clear your email address
    edress = ""
 Next r

 'clear memory of used objects:
 Set outlookapp = Nothing: Set outlookmailitem = Nothing
 Set wdDoc = Nothing: Set oRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Please, send some feedback after testing it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help so far! I've tried the above code but when running I get runtime error 13: type mismatch. I've tried adding the final row number in the following line:
Set rngVis = Sheet1.Range("A3:J" & lastR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) - to see if that solves the problem, but that didn't work..

Comment: @noavdk Only mentioning the error number without specifying on which code line the code is raised, is useless... So, on which line is the error raised?

Comment: Sorry I thought I did mention that. When I step through the macro line by line, the error is generated when stepping from the following line:
edress = r.Cells(r, 7) 'extract the necessary values from the iterated row
to this one:
cc1 = r.Cells(r, 8)
> meaning that the error is in the first line right?

Comment: @noavdk Ups... I was lasy and not replaced original `r` (1, 7) with 1... I will adapt the above code. Adapted...

Comment: @noavdk If you look of the code, I forgot replacing **exactly** on that line... But you could do it, I think, since I tried explaining where the problem is. I will correct that line, too. Corrected. I tried keeping from your code as much as I could, and I forgot adapting the code to read **in a row** and `r` being a `Range` not a `Long`, anymore. It is good to try understanding what's happening, why does it not work, how to correct it and so on...

Comment: Yes you're correct :) ! I checked it again and then changed the last line to 1 as well and now it's running! Thanks a lot for your help, I'm still relatively new with VBA so this was very insightfull!

Comment: @noavdk Have a nice day, too!